# occasionally problems with invokerequired in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I'm having problems with the invokerequired method from time to time and wanted to aks if someone knows that problem or can it explain to me. I have some code:

```
 splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance();

        if (thrd == null)
        {
            thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadingScreenStart));
            thrd.IsBackground = true;
            thrd.Start();
        }

        else
        {
            if (splashObj.InvokeRequired)
            {
                splashObj.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    splashObj.Show();
                }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                splashObj.Show();
            }
        }

        if (splashObj.loadLabel.InvokeRequired)
        {
            splashObj.loadLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                splashObj.loadLabel.Text = "Checking Username...";
            }
            );
        }
        else
        {
            splashObj.loadLabel.Text = "Checking Username...";
        }


  public void loadingScreenStart()
    {
        splashScreen splashObj = splashScreen.GetInstance();
        Application.Run(splashScreen.GetInstance());
    }
```

the splashscreen code:

```
 public partial class splashScreen : Form
{

    public Form1 form1;

    public splashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //form1 = frm1;
    }

    public splashScreen(Form1 frm1)
    {
        form1 = frm1;
    }


    private void splashScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private static splashScreen m_instance = null;
    private static object m_instanceLock = new object();

    public static splashScreen GetInstance()
    {

        lock (m_instanceLock)
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new splashScreen();
            }
        }

        return m_instance;
    }
}
```

So I'm showing a splashscreen while the rest of the code is loading in the background. Messages are getting showed like "Checking Username...", "Checking Password...", "Loading..." and so on.
This code works fine but from time to time it seems like the code execution is faster than the thread and then I get an error that the method was called from an other thread than the one it was created on. Why does this happen? Is there any solution for this kind of problem? That happens maybe once in twenty executions.

Comment: The "if (thrd==null)" construct is rather unusual. Also your code sample is not complete - how is it called? Besides - the splashObj.loadLabel part should probably be moved to the first else branch.

Comment: You can't just start a thread and expect it to be done by the time the `Start` call finishes. It will take some time to initialize the splashscreen form and call the `Application.Run` - until all of that happens, you can't work with the form. Also, the logic for showing the text should be in the splash form, that's who's responsible for showing it. Then it could simply make sure that it's already initialized (it could wait for a `ManualResetEvent` that's `Set` in the `Load` event, for example). It's called synchronization, and it's absolutely necessary in shared memory multi-threading.

Comment: Off topic. If you're using .NET 3.5 or above, instead of `Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()` you could use a bit of lambda and change it to `Invoke(new Action(() => `

Comment: Really, just the fact that you're using `InvokeRequired` *broadcasts* how blurry your vision what's going on is. How could there ever be a case when it wasn't required? There's a reason why using `InvokeRequired` is considered a code smell, and your code isn't in any way special :)

Comment: It should be complete I think. Did I miss something? Is it possible somehow to hold the execution of the code till the thread is fully loaded? something like a routine in GO ? - I don't know much about that since I'm working with C# for only a couple of months

Comment: @ScorpX Yes, search for "synchronization primitives" - the `ManualResetEvent` I suggested is one of those. You can use `Task` to run an asynchronous task and wait for it (or even better, `await`), but that wouldn't work here because the thread you have only exits when you close the splash screen (`Application.Run` is a blocking call).

Comment: Ok so how to fix that with the code sample exactly? I'm a little bit confused about that

Comment: - I've seen it can be done with locks, semaphores etc but I had these only in theory. Don't know how to use them in this example.

Comment: It's my sincere hope that Luann's answer gets you back on the right track. If not though, please edit the question to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that (as much as possible) reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-threading is hard, so you should try making it as simple as possible. One, there's no reason to have any of the splashscreen code outside of the splashscreen class itself. Second, you should always know what you're doing, so `InvokeRequired` is just a code smell that says "I have no idea who's going to call this method".

```
void Main()
{
    SplashScreen.ShowText("Loading 1");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    SplashScreen.ShowText("Loading 2");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    SplashScreen.Done();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    SplashScreen.ShowText("Loading 3");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
  private static SplashScreen instance;
  private static readonly ManualResetEvent initEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  Label loadLabel;

  private SplashScreen()
  {
    // InitializeComponent();
    loadLabel = new Label();
    Controls.Add(loadLabel);

    Load += (s, e) => initEvent.Set();
    Closing += (s, e) => initEvent.Reset();
  }

  private static object syncObject = new object();
  private static void InitializeIfRequired()
  {
    // If not set, we'll have to init the message loop
    if (!initEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
      lock (syncObject)
      {
        // Someone initialized it before us
        if (initEvent.WaitOne(0)) return;

        // Recreate the form if it was closed
        instance = new SplashScreen();

        var thread = new Thread(() => { Application.Run(instance); });
        thread.Start();

        // Wait until the form is ready
        initEvent.WaitOne();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void ShowText(string text)
  {
    InitializeIfRequired();

    instance.Invoke((Action)(() => 
     { 
       if (!instance.IsDisposed) instance.loadLabel.Text = text; 
     }
    ));
  }

  public static void Done()
  {
    // Is it closed already?
    if (!initEvent.WaitOne(0)) return;

    lock (syncObject)
    {
      // Someone closed it before us
      if (!initEvent.WaitOne(0)) return;

      instance.Invoke((Action)(() => { instance.Close(); }));
    }
  }
}
```

This is a snippet for LINQPad, you'll want to remove the comment on `InitializeComponent` as well as the `loadLabel` control (which should be on the designer instead).

This way, you have the logic of the splash screen completely isolated from the rest of the application. To show a splashscreen text, just call `SplashScreen.ShowText`. To make the splashscreen go away, call `SplashScreen.Done`.

Note how there's no need to use `InvokeRequired` - there's no way any legitimate call of `SplashScreen.ShowText` (or `Done`) would ever *not* need marshalling to the UI thread of the splash screen.

Now, this is not perfect. It's something I wrote in about 10 minutes. But it's (probably :)) thread-safe, follows best practices a lot better than the original, and is much easier to use.

Also, there's cases where I would use higher-level constructs, e.g. `Lazy<T>` and `Task` - but since that wouldn't really help here (starting the new messaging loop, having to recreate the form if it was closed...), I opted for the simpler solution instead.

Note that I'm using `Invoke` rather than `BeginInvoke` or similar - this is quite important, because otherwise it would be possible to queue a close, followed by a `ShowText` that would work on a disposed form. If you intend to call `ShowText` from multiple threads, it would be safer to also lock around the whole `ShowText` body. Given the usual use case for splash screens, there's some thread-safety that's unnecessary, but...

Comment: The problem I got is that I want to show a progress to the user. For that reason I've got a ProgressBar and change that on certain places in the code (with the text that is shown to the user). So when he executed a couple of code it changes. How to manage that?

Comment: @ScorpX Just make a `ShowProgress` method that has the same body and changes the label *and* the progress bar. There's no need to expose the label or progress bar to the outside directly. Keep private everything that doesn't need to be public :)

Comment: _"there's no way any legitimate call of SplashScreen.ShowText (or Done) would ever not need marshalling"_ -- agreed, but it's even worse than that. The `Invoke()` method _already does this check_. It has to, otherwise it would deadlock itself. So even if it's possible for some code to sometimes be executed on the UI thread and sometimes not (which frankly pretty much never happens in real life...if someone is checking `InvokeRequired`, they already know the answer, as here), the code can just always call `Invoke()` and the right thing happens.

Comment: I will also point out: while I agree with what you've written, it's not clear to me that any of this really helps the OP fix his immediate problem. The most likely explanation for what he's seeing is that `InvokeRequired` returns `false` even when he's on the wrong thread; the way this usually happens is that the window handle hasn't been created yet, but just switching to always calling `Invoke()` isn't going to help fix that. He needs more repairs to the code that just that, and without a good code example, it's not really possible to say exactly what.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yeah. The only place where there's any need for `InvokeRequired` at all (and even then it still smells) is when you're using `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke`. Apart from `Invoke` being *slightly* more expensive, but then again - we're working with the UI, it's probably negligible :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Actually, that's why I'm synchronously waiting on the `initEvent` wait handle - it's only set when the form is ready. I've changed a lot more than just the `Invoke` calls :))

Comment: IMHO, `BeginInvoke()` needs `InvokeRequired` even less, since if one is calling that, one clearly doesn't care exactly when the invoke happens. And yes, it's a tiny bit more expensive to call `Invoke()` than just some code directly, but as you say: negligible. As for the MRE, I do _hope_ that fixes the problem, but there's not enough code in the OP to know for sure that's the window handle that needs waiting one. :( You are right though, I implied (but didn't mean) that all you'd suggested was switching to `Invoke()`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the help! I will rewrite it and hope it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this problem still exists, it can happen when your thread is calling the form before it shows; both *InvokeRequired* and *BeginInvoke* may fail.

A solution is to start your thread on form event *Shown*:

```
/// <summary>
/// Testing form
/// </summary>
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Work work
    /// </summary>
    private Thread _MyThread;

    /// <summary>
    /// New test form
    /// </summary>
    public MyForm()
    {
        // Initialize components
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// First time form is show
    /// </summary>
    private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create and start thread
        this._MyThread = new Thread(this.MyThreadWork);
        this._MyThread.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Doing some work here
    /// </summary>
    private void MyThreadWork()
    {
        // Counting time
        int count = 0;

        // Forever and ever
        while (true)
        {
            this.PrintInfo((count++).ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Printing info into form title
    /// </summary>
    private void PrintInfo(string info)
    {
        // Needs to sync?
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // Sync me
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(this.PrintInfo), info);
        }
        else
        {
            // Prints info
            this.Text = info;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Good bye form, don't miss the work work
    /// </summary>
    private void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Kill worker
        this._MyThread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Some will just add a Thread.Sleep before first PrintInfo but common, what sleep time do you would use? 1, 10, 100? Depends on how fast your form will show.